# Does method 'jwplayer(div).setup()' accept option 'streamer'?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, red5

I try to understand how red5 works. I have looked at standard examples provided in the red5server installation directory. The 'ofla-demo' example appeared to be the most relevant.
In this example index.html contains the following piece of code:

```
<div id='mediaspace2'>This text will be replaced</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer('mediaspace2').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
    'file': 'skywalker.mp4',
    'streamer': 'rtmpt://localhost:5080/oflaDemo',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '720',
    'height': '480'
  });
</script>
```

When I removed the parameter 'streamer' nothing has actually changed. It kept working as it did before.
I was curious about the purpose of this parameter. Looked for it in the [documentation](https://docs.jwplayer.com/players/reference/setup-options), but could not find it.

Could someone explain, why would it be included if it does not exist?

Comment: Could you provide the link to the relevant demo?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski, https://github.com/Red5/red5-examples/blob/master/oflaDemo/src/main/webapp/index.html